# Conversion of numeric vector to date

Tags: r, date, dataframe, posixct

I have a dataframe with a date column like the following:

```
19870703
19920929
20051015
20030613
```

How can I change the numeric Data to a Date format like %Y%m%d?
Neither as.date() nor as.POSIX.ct() works?

Comment: `as.Date("19870703", "%Y%m%d")` should work

Comment: Unfortunately not .. If I use as.Date I just get a bunch of NAs.

Comment: Even with `%Y%m%d` ? Running this 1-by-1 works. Could you please post a sample frame with what you currently have? EDIT: After trying this again in a frame, converting the column to character worked `as.Date(as.character(df$date),"%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Conceptually, this is not a numeric vector but a character vector. Thus, you need to ensure that you import as a character vector to R. Then the proposed solutions will work.

Comment: If your data is numeric, you need to convert it to character before applying `as.Date`

Answer (score 2):

Using lubridate

```
date <- ymd("19870703")
```

in place of date you can put your column name

Answer (score 0):

```
as.Date("19870703", "%Y%m%d")
[1] "1987-07-03"
```

Apply for entire column.

Comment: Data$Eintrittsdatum <- as.Date(Data$Eintrittsdatum, "%Y%m%d")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0):

```
library(date)
as.date(your.date.vector)
```